# How to remove duplicate text from two different files in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My problem: I have two files, "text1.txt" and "text2.txt"

**"Text1.txt" contains the following:**

```
Banana, rotten
Apple, ripe
Cheese, fresh
```

**and "Text2.txt" contains the following:**

```
Banana, good
Dragon, edible
Cheese, nice
```

What I want is to create a code that would check text2.txt with text1.txt and remove the word and the whole line that repeats itself before the comma. So, in this case, it would look like this:
**"Text1.txt" changed to** and Text2.txt would be left unchanged

```
Apple, ripe
```

What I managed to do is check if the words are duplicates without the comma, but even struggled to do that. My attempt is below:

```
New_food = open("text1.txt", "r+")
All_food = open("text2.txt")
food = New_food.readlines()
food2 = All_food.readlines()

#The following calculates how many lines the text file has
def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as s:
        for t, l in enumerate(s):
            pass
    return t+1

#calculates line number
n = file_len("text1.txt")
m = file_len("text2.txt")

for g in range(n):
    food_r = food[g]
    for j in range(m):
        food2_r = food2[j]
        if food_r == food2_r:
            print(5) #only when they match
```

I have made the line break before it reaches a comma using this piece of code:

```
word = "cheese , fresh"
type_, *vals = word.split(',')
print(type_) #this would return cheese
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote some of your code into the following script:

```
file1 = open("text1.txt", "r+")
file2 = open("text2.txt")

# List from files
food_list_1 = file1.readlines()
food_list_2 = file2.readlines()

# Unique food values in list
file_2_only_foods = list()

for line in food_list_2:
    file_2_only_foods.append(line.split(',')[0])


def determine(x):
    type = x.split(',')[0]
    return type in file_2_only_foods


result = [x for x in food_list_1 if not determine(x)]
file1.close()

file1 = open("text1.txt", 'w')
file1.writelines(result)
```

This will put all the unique values into file_2_only_foods list to check if the values from list 1 are unique are not.
In order to write the file, we have to close the previous file and than reopen it to write your results. The result from my code is the exact same as what you described.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no duplicates within files, you could go through both files and add all elements to a Counter (https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html), and then on a second pass remove all elements that have a count larger than 1.

```
from collections import Counter 
>>> food1 = open("Text1.txt")
>>> food2 = open("Text2.txt")
>>> counter1 = Counter(item.split(",")[0] for item in food1.readlines())
>>> counter2 = Counter(item.split(",")[0] for item in food2.readlines())
>>> counter = counter1 + counter2
Counter({'Cheese': 2, 'Banana': 2, 'Apple': 1, 'Dragon': 1})
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem presented in the question. Using a Counter is adding overhead when a set could be used to get a list of filter words,  and how are you going to write the lines back out to a file in the right order?

Answer (score 1):

you can use **regular expressions** to extract the words from the text. Regular expressions reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

You can extract all the first words from a file with this one-liner:

```
re.findall(r"^\s*(\w+)", file.read(), re.MULTILINE)
```

Demo:

```
>>> txt = """
... Banana, rotten
... Apple, ripe
... Cheese, fresh
... """
>>> 
>>> re.findall(r"^\s*(\w+)", txt, re.MULTILINE)
['Banana', 'Apple', 'Cheese']
>>>
```

Extracts all the words to filter on, then efficiently filters the target file line-by-line.

```
>>> def filter_lines(filter_path, target_path, output_path):
...
...     with open(filter_path, 'r' ) as filter_file,
...          open(target_path, 'r' ) as target_file,
...          open(output_path, 'w+') as output_file:
...
...         filter_words = re.findall(r"^\s*(\w+)", 
...                                   filter_file.read(), 
...                                   re.MULTILINE)
...         filter_words = set(filter_words)
...
...         for line in target_file:
...             m = re.findall(r"^\s*(\w+)", line)
...             if not (m and m[0] in filter_words):
...                 output_file.write(line)
>>>
>>> filter_lines('text2.txt', 'text1.txt', 'filtered_text1.txt')
>>>
```

side note: Generally, in cases where you need to maintain a large list of items that's used in expressions like `if item in long_list:`, where the list is checked for membership. A `set` is much better than a list because lookups are fast; with `list`'s, lookups are done by iterating over all items until what you're looking for is found.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation!